# How can i pass parameter to LIMIT ? Can i save all query output in one string?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, serial-port

I have 2 questions, kind of related:

1).How can i pass the value of a parameter to limit ? is it possible ?

i tried with this:

```
log.CommandText = "SELECT * from log order by date desc limit ?param1";
```

but it doesnt work because the parameter is passed like: "2".

SOLVED with:

```
log.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * from log order by date desc limit {0}, yourIntNumber)
```

2). Can i save the output of the query above in one variable in C#?
i tried something like this.. but logs does not contain everything..

```
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(lognr); i++)
                    {

                        logs = logs + (Reader.GetValue(i).ToString());  
                    }

                }
```

Comment: What database are you using?  If SQL Server, you use TOP N not LIMIT N.  Also, what does this have to do with `serial-port`?

Comment: @EricJ.: i use mysql, the value of param is from serial port. maybe this info could help

Comment: I don't understand why parameter is passed like "2", instead of 2. Have you tried to use `log.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * from log order by date desc limit {0}, yourIntNumber)` ?

Comment: this is the error i get: {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 1"}

Comment: it seems to work with limit {0}, yourIntNumber. thx :D

Answer (score 0):

For your first qustion :-

You can use Top keyword e.g :-
For MSSQL (Microsoft SQL)

```
Select TOP 3 * From Table_name
```

For MYSQL

```
Select * From Table_name LIMIT 3
```

Above will return top 3 rows.

For your second question,

```
while (Reader.Read())
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(lognr); i++)
       {

        logs = logs + (Reader.GetValue(i).ToString());  
        }

   }
}
```

This code is checking the condition Convert.ToInt16(lognr) and that's why it is not returning everything.

Hope above information will help you :)

Comment: top is not working for me, even if had top there is still that problem, when i pass the param to the query, the query will not be like: select top 3 * from log, but it would be like: select top "3" * from log.

Comment: Top n will work in Sql-Server, not in mySql. He specified that he use MySql in his question!

Comment: Ohh my bad, I thought you are using MSSQL,

Comment: you can go with Select * From Table_name LIMIT 3 if you are using MYSQL

Comment: Thanks ElVieejo for highlighting :)

Answer (score 0):

1).How can i pass the value of a parameter to limit ? is it possible ?

i tried with this:

```
log.CommandText = "SELECT * from log order by date desc limit ?param1";
```

but it doesnt work because the parameter is passed like: "2".

SOLVED with:

```
log.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * from log order by date desc limit {0}, yourIntNumber)
```

2). Can i save the output of the query above in one variable in C#? i tried something like this.. but logs does not contain everything..

```
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(lognr); i++)
            {

                logs = logs + (Reader.GetValue(i).ToString());  
            }

        }
```

Solved:

```
log.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * from log order by date desc limit {0}", lognr);  //the output has 3 columns and several rows.
Reader = log.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;
while (Reader.Read())
{
logs = logs + "\r\n" + Reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + " " + Reader.GetValue(1).ToString() + " "+ " " + Reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
i++;
}
```